# How should comments containing spam be handled/flagged?

Tags: discussion, comment-flags

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45328473/) (now deleted) inside [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24545949/) this morning as spam.

The person also added a comment under their answer containing the same text as given in the answer.

I know that the flags recently have been changed, so I am a bit in the dark on how to handle certain things for now.

It seems that the "rude or abusive" and "no longer needed" options didn't seem to quite fit the bill.

For then and for future reference in regards to a comment being as potential spam, my question being:

- What should I do when I see spam in comments?

FYI: The answer and comment read as:

> *"Are you looking for a Good Loan lender and a honest company who can help you out with a loan? if yes, i know of a good and honest loan lender who i get my loan funds from that can help you with a loan, contact her via email: (Larryadams252@gmail.com) – Christopher Adams"*.

And a screenshot for those who can't see the post due to lower rep.

[image]

Comment: Mostly because commenting everywhere requires 50 reputation. A spammer wouldn't usually have that and would only be able to comment on their posts (and answers to their questions). Given that the posts can be flagged, why also add such flagging to comments?

Comment: @Oded I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Fred-ii- - what can I clarify?

Comment: *"why also add such flagging to comments?"* - Well, say for instance if there was a member who could comment under another answer or a question containing a message like that, you figure that the comment should be flagged as spam, that is the reason for my question. and for your *"because commenting everywhere requires 50 reputation"* comment.

Comment: But how often do members who are not spammers post spam comments? They don't. And the case you have shown us - this is a spammer commenting on their spam post.

Comment: @Oded I realize that but say there was a member who could do that and had enough rep to comment (pre-planned for instance to spam the system). I'm just trying to potentially stop those people *dead in their tracks*.

Comment: We solve problems that are real - not things that are possible abuses (if we see this become a problem, then we will tackle it)

Comment: *"not things that are possible abuses"* - @Oded I'm trying to help in fighting possible future problems like this. My question was *"should it have been flagged to a moderator instead? If not, which one?"* I figured I'd just get an answer for it; it seems I was given one by George and flag to a moderator then. Was this a bad question btw?

Comment: @Servy Fair enough. What do you suggest I do to my question, leave it or rephrase it completely?

Comment: [Spammers are *very* lazy](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?feedback_filter=tp).  Posting a comment requires 50 reputation, which requires them to post quality content.  That takes *effort*.  Furthermore, if spammers start contributing quality content to earn rep, then...[mission accomplished](https://xkcd.com/810/).

Comment: Thanks @Servy I made an edit and also changed the title. I hope it's clearer/better now.

Comment: @NobodyNada I disagree.  I don't think it takes *that much effort*.  Considering you get +2 rep for every approved edit, no matter how minor, you could get a comment-privelaged user rather quickly.  I'd imagine you could even find a way to automate the process by just boldening keywords.

Comment: @zero298 In practice, that’s *very* rare.  Spammers do the minimum amount of work required to get their spam onto the site.  Sure, such an attack is conceivable, but past experience shows it doesn’t happen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [Oded's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353848/why-a-comment-cant-be-flagged-as-spam#comment497195_353848), spam comments from real users are not yet a problem that needs a separate solution in addition to regular "needs moderator attention" flags.

Commenting requires 50 rep and most spam posts are made by disposable 1-point accounts.

If you see true spam comment from a 50+rep user, you can flag for "requires moderator intervention" with a reasonable explanation. You can also spend a couple extra minutes to see if the account is an obvious part of a voting ring to make your flag even better.

In this particular case a 1-rep user was able to comment on their own spam post - so flagging the post itself is the correct action (comments will be gone as part of removal and there is no value of extra -100 points as user has only 1 anyway).